# Magento 2: How to get additional attribute in a separate column while Export products?

Tags: magento2, importexport

I want to get an additional attribute in a separate column while Export products.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the text to column function in your sheet editor and later use the TEXTJOIN function.
In Google spreadsheets, the function looks like this:
=textjoin(","; TRUE; A2:C2) Change the cells to your needs offcourse.

There is no way you can get the additional attributes out of the box. There are several extension that can do so but the methode above works just fine for me.